# Unable to link volatility structure to swaption pricing engine

Tags: option-pricing, volatility, swaption

Good morning,

I am trying to link the volatility surface to my swaption pricing engine.

```
swaptionVolMatrix = ql.SwaptionVolatilityMatrix(calendar, rollConvention, optionTenors, swapTenors, ql.Matrix(normal_vols),dayCountConvention, False, ql.Normal)
#Matrix is a 8x6 shape

swaptionVolHandle = ql.SwaptionVolatilityStructureHandle(swaptionVolMatrix)
swaptionVolHandle.enableExtrapolation()
```

I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: BlackSwaptionEngine requires (shifted) lognormal input volatility here:

blackEngine = ql.BlackSwaptionEngine(discountingTermStructure, swaptionVolHandle)
```

I have tried to follow this from the documentation:
[image]

Do I need to extrapolate manually first then? And insert just the quote value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message says that the Black surface requires lognormal vols. You provide the argument ```ql.Normal``` when setting up ```SwaptionVolatilityMatrix```. I think you simply need to change accordingly.

Comment: … and you must provide lognormal vols, of course